Can't connect properly firebase hosting with squarespace domain for a new Angular website
I developed a website using Angular, I want to publish it online and bought a domain from Squarespace.com. After that if I go to mydomain.com it apper a default squarespace page with the indication "We're under construction. Please check back for an update soon".
After that I choose firebase hosting for deploy my angular website. Following the instruction I installed firebase with npm and I updated my app component and deployed my application, so I see it online on the two firebase default domains: mydomain.web.app and mydomain.firebase.com. So, I started to configure my custom domain following the instruction: I deleted the defaul record with the 4 IPs from squarespace dns setting page, I copied the A (wita a new IP) and TXT record given by firebase and tried to verified. At firs I had some issues. I had errors on the verifications, so I discovered that squarespace want @ in the Host section and not the domain. After that modify, I encountered another issues: 404 Not Found on ACME challenge. I solved it on firebase using the redirect option from www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com. The next step was to add on DNS config of squarespace the CNAME record and now my custom domain result connected on firebase.
My issue is the following: even if the custom domain is connected on mydomain.com I still see the default squarespace page. At first I had my website on the default firebase domains even after new firebase deploy command, but I tried to use the firebase init command and after that a deploy. Now the default firebase domains doesn't works and open a page with the following message: "Firebase Hosting Setup Complete
You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!". In the custom domain I still see the default squarespace page.
A strange things is that I checked the dns setting page on squarespace and I have 6 records: the TXT given by firebase; the CNAME given by firebase; the 4 A records with 4 IPs as values, the original ones from squarespace. If I try to delete those A record and insert the IP given by firebase during the config and save, apparently works, but if I reload the page there are still the 4 squarespace IPs.
How can I solve?

I guess your domain is not connected to your project. Did you follow this document?

Yes I did and my custom domain is in the state connected at the end of that document

Was your issue solved? It sounds like an issue on a Squarespace side. Did you try to contact their helpdesk? Looking forward to hearing from you.
